# Writing Classes classes and then implementing them

Tags: java, class

I have written a class called ' bug ' with many methods (mostly just get. and set.) intending too represent a bug on a wire who can move left, right, change direction, and retrace his steps. I have written the code for the bug object but have clearly made a mistake as my output is way off. hoping there is just a logical error I've overlooked.

I'm just posting the coding of me using the bug object, and not the code creating the object itself, but I can post that if it will help.

I am new to coding, just started learning online at my school. I have tried adding a default statement under my main method but it kept saying "orphaned default" which I haven't encountered before.

```
    public class DemoBug
    {

        public static void main( String[] args)
        {
        bug b = new bug(0, "right");

        System.out.println("Bug is facing" + b.getDirection());

        for(int x = 0; x<10; x++)
        {
           b.retrace();
            System.out.println(b);
        }

        System.out.println("Bug is changing direction");
        b.turn();

        System.out.println("Bug is moving " + b.getDirection());
        for(int i = 0; 1<10; i++)
        {
            b.retrace();
            System.out.println(b);
        }
        }
}
```

I am adding the bug class as per request

```
public class bug
{
    //things declared at class level here
    private int startingPosition, getPosition, currentposition;
    private int position; 
    private String currentDirection, getDirection;


    //constucotr: sets initial position of the bug
    public bug()
    {
        startingPosition = 0;
        currentDirection = "right";
    }

    public bug(int sp, String cd)
    {
        startingPosition = sp;
        currentDirection = cd;
    }

    public void setPosition(int a)
    {
        startingPosition = a;
    }

    public int getPosition()
    {
        return startingPosition;

    }
    public void setDirection(String s)
    {
        if(currentDirection == "right")
        {
            currentDirection = s;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("The bug is facing left");
        }
    }

    public String getDirection()
    {
        return currentDirection;
    } 

    public void turn()
    {
        if(currentDirection == "left")
        {
            currentDirection = "right";
        }
        else
        {
            currentDirection = "left";
        }
    }

    public void retrace()
    {
        if(currentDirection.equals("right"))
            currentDirection = "left";
         else
            if(currentDirection.equals("left"))
                currentDirection = "right";
}

    public void move()
    {
        if(currentDirection.equals("right"))
            startingPosition++;
        else 
            if(currentDirection.equals("left"))
            startingPosition--;
        }   
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Bug is now at" + startingPosition;
        }
}
```

the expected output is something along the lines of :
"bug is moving right"
"bug is at 1"
"bug is at 2"
"bug is changing direction"
"bug is facing left"
"bug is at 2"
"but is at 1"
this would be best case scenario at this point, but my current output is just
"bug is at0" and I have to force quit as the program won't stop compiling

Comment: Can you show the `Bug` class? It's probably got to do with how you implemented `retrace`...

Comment: I've added it to the post! thank you

Comment: Currently, `retrace` does roughly the same as `turn`. That’s not what it’s supposed to do, is it? What is `retrace` supposed to do?

Comment: `currentDirection == "right"` is not how you compare `String`s in Java, you're suppose to use `currentDirection.equals("right")` or variant

Comment: `retrace` is just going to make you go around in circles.  If your want a "real" re-trace, you probably need to investigate a queue of some kind, where you can "push" each action onto as they occur and, when you need to, "pop" the action off, which will take you back one step

Comment: I've taken the entire retrace method out of the code, but now the only output of my program is "the bug is moving-2344" (the numbers speed by going way past that value). Im not sure how to cleaning end the program, and get the other outputs i.e "bug is changing direction" to print. any ideas?